# how to construct BDD from huge logic expression?

Tags: logic, satisfiability, multivalued-logic

I have a multi-valued discrete logic expression looks like this:

```
0.03*A+0.005*B+0.4*C+... + 0.006*N >= 0
```

It has 14 variables (from A to N), each variable has dozens of discrete values (take variable A for example, A1,A2,A3...A31), which makes it impossible to calculate the exhaustive list of all possible values due to combination explosion (it has more than 100 PB combinations).

I want to get its multi-valued decision diagram (MDD). How can I get it in practical time/cpu overhead?

I have done a little bit research, and it seems all current methods (in my humble knowledge) need to know the decision trees or truth tables before they generate BDD out of the decision trees or truth tables.

I have tried to solve it by brute force, but it seems impossible to finish or store all the results (with more than 100 PB combinations).